# Are meshes in a urdf limited to a number of faces?

Tags: ros, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are meshes like .stls and .daes limited in the number of faces so that a urdf will be loaded properly in rviz?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384312/are-meshes-in-a-urdf-limited-to-a-number-of-faces?/) by [JoSch](https://answers.ros.org/users/72373/josch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Theoretically: no.

Practically: yes.

There is no hard-coded limit to the size of meshes in RViz -- or more precisely: in Assimp, which is what RViz uses to load meshes.

Practically though, loading times will increase and framerates will start to drop for larger meshes, but it's hard to put an exact number of faces on that, as it's largely hardware dependent.

Perhaps also important: loading a urdf is (almost) separate from loading the meshes. Many consumers of `.urdf`s will load the XML, but will not bother with loading the meshes.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-08-12**:
PS: also be aware that RViz is not the only consumer of URDFs. And it's also not special.

Consumers such as MoveIt for instance load the same data, and *there* collision checking performance is highly dependent on the number of faces in a mesh (as without capsules, collision checking will be face-based).